# CustomArrayAdapter android nullpointerexception

Tags: java, android, android-listview, nullpointerexception, android-arrayadapter

Can anyone tell me why I am facing a nullpointerexception on super method in the constructor?

It always faces null pointer exception in super but the context and historyItems are not null.

```
public class HistoryItemAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<HistoryItem> {

    Context context;
    HistoryItem[] historyItems=null;

    public HistoryItemAdapter(Context context, HistoryItem[] historyItems) {
        super(context,R.layout.list_history_single,historyItems); //Exception Here
        this.context = context;
        this.historyItems = historyItems;
    }

    private class ViewHolder {
        TextView historyName;
        TextView historyTitle;
        ImageView historyImage;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder viewHolder;
        if(convertView==null) {
            viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity) context).getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_history_single,null);
            viewHolder.historyName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_name);
            viewHolder.historyTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_title);
            viewHolder.historyImage = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.history_image);
            convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
        } else {
            viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        HistoryItem historyItem = historyItems[position];

        viewHolder.historyImage.setImageBitmap(historyItem.bitmap);
        viewHolder.historyName.setText(historyItem.name);
        viewHolder.historyTitle.setText(historyItem.title);

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Comment: is  historyItems null??

Comment: propably somewhere here `R.layout.list_history_single`. `R` or `R.layout` could be null

Comment: and what about `HistoryItem[] historyItems=null;` as @jucas mentioned? Yours constructor parameter has the same name as property - whitch is set to `null`.

Comment: Please post the complete logcat error trace.

Comment: @michasm: If variable name is same then local one is used. Can't be issue here. We need logcat trace.

Comment: @Rohit5k2 - yes, you're right.

Comment: @goonerdroid Logcat:- http://pastebin.com/UTCvhWmE ReportHistoryFragment:- http://pastebin.com/ix1tiKiU list_history_single.xml:- http://pastebin.com/wiyE9cr0

Comment: @Rohit5k2 see the links for logcat

Answer (score 0):

The value you are passing in your adapter is null because

1. You haven't initialized it.
2. Initialization is done in a background operation which is called after assignment of the adapter in the listview.

Initialize your variable like this

```
HistoryItem[] historyItem = new HistoryItem[size];
```

and when you are done downloading your data call this

```
adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

But seems you don't know the size before it starts downloading. In that case you can move this code

```
adapter = new HistoryItemAdapter(context,historyItem);
listView = (ListView) reportHistory.findViewById(R.id.list_history);
listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

inside your method `done()` which is callback of your background task.

Comment: Okay now i am facing another issue. Its null pointer exception in my custom adapter. It shows nullpointerexception when i try to set the bitmap to an image view but bitmap is not null. ReportHistoryFragment.java(new):-http://pastebin.com/vwRUMuqa  ReportHistoryAdapter:- http://pastebin.com/gPFgPuY2

Comment: happens not only in image but also for name and title

Comment: logcat and class file looks out of sync. Have you make any changes after uploading the class. Logcat says error is in line 53. but that's not possible. there isnt a real code in that line.

Comment: I am sorry I made a change I reverted it back and applied your code. still the same error. here is the link to new logcat. http://pastebin.com/19nstVs7

Comment: There is something wrong with the History item array. You need to put breakpoint and debug it. I can't be sure what is wrong by just looking at code.

Comment: I put a breakpoint ran the app using debugmode worked perfectly run the same code in release version it crashes.

Comment: This seem to be unrelated to the original question. Please post a new question for this.

Answer (score 0):

You have 2 parameters in your constructor, but your `super` has 3 parameters.